# Count occurences of strings in a text file

Tags: python, counter

I have the following program and I want to find for example the string 'light pink' in my text file!
I use `word==' '.join(['light','pink'])` and it doesn't works.

```
from operator import itemgetter

def mmetric1(file):
    words_gen = (word.lower() for line in open("test.txt")
                                             for word in line.split())
    words = {}

    for word in words_gen:
        if (word=='aqua')or(word=='azure')or(word=='black')or(word=='light pink'):
            words[word] = words.get(word, 0) + 1

    top_words = sorted(words.items(), key=itemgetter(1))

    for word, frequency in top_words:
       print ("%s : %d" % (word, frequency))
```

Comment: you should consider using regex.

Comment: Have a look at [Aho-Corasick algorithm](https://hkn.eecs.berkeley.edu/~dyoo/python/ahocorasick/)

Comment: Protecting this question, asked many years ago by an inactive user, unlikely to get an accepted answer - and just attracting bad edits.

Answer (score 1):

You have already split the entire line into separate words:

```
for word in line.split()
```

So there is no single word in `words_gen` which contains the text `light pink`. It instead contains `light` and `pink` as two separate words, along with all the other words on that line.

You need a different approach; have a look at regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Your entire approach is wrong.

It seems to me you want to check if a set of strings exist in your file. You should use regular expressions.

Here:

```
from collections import Counter
import re

def mmetric1(file_path, desired):
    finder = re.compile(re.escape('(%s)' % '|'.join(desired)), re.MULTILINE)
    with open(file_path) as f:
        return Counter(finder.findall(f))

# have a list of the strings you want to find
desired = ['aqua', 'azure', 'black', 'light pink']
# run the method
mmetric1(file_path, desired)
```

---

If you are worried about large files, and performance, you can iterate over the lines in the file:

```
def mmetric1(file_path, desired):
    results = Counter()
    finder = re.compile(re.escape('(%s)' % '|'.join(desired)))
    with open(file_path) as f:
        for line in f:
            Counter.update(finder.findall(line))
    return results
```

---

To print these results as you have your own:

```
for word, frequency in mmetric1(file_path, desired).items():
    print ("%s : %d" % (word, frequency))
```

Comment: Because i am a beginner in coding Python in argument file_path what can i write? i want to load the "test.txt" file

Comment: Yes, you need to simply put the path to the file as `file_path`, you had used `file` as the variable name, and `file` is a Python type, you were shadowing it.

Comment: You mean that in argument file_path i must write something like "C://Python27/test.txt", i ask you because in editor shows me this problem Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\mmetric1.py", line 12, in <module>
    mmetric1(file_path, desired)
NameError: name 'file_path' is not defined

Comment: Don't you know how functions work? I can't help you if you don't understand how Python works. Let us say your path is `file_path = r"C:\temp\text.txt"` (note the `r` for a raw string) and your word list is `desired = ['aqua', 'azure', 'black', 'light pink']` simply pass those variables to the function as in the last code bock of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you split a string, its splits based on whitespace, which includes space character

So later, there would be no possibility for you to match consecutive words in the manner you are proposing to peruse except IF

- You wan't to modify your loop

Example Code

```
try:
   while True:
        word = next(words_gen)
       if any(word == token for token in ['aqua', 'azure', 'black']) \
          or (word == 'light' and  next(word) == 'pink'):
            words[word] = words.get(word, 0) + 1 
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

- Use Regex

Not a good option, if you are searching a huge file

- Use some other data-structure like prefix Tree

Comment: you mean that i will add an exception in my program?

Comment: @user2314768: Using Exception for control flow is acceptable in Python World